# Derived class from model with additionally configured navigational properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-relationship

To note: My database is already written in sql, the EF setup does not impact actual creation of SQL objects.

I'm trying to create a "base" Context and Models that other projects can inherit from with the hope that the base Context and Models will not need to be modified, but extended as additional relationships are built. This is my attempt so far

File 1:

```
namespace BaseProject.Models {
   public class ClassA {
      public int Id { get;set; }
      public string Value { get; set; }
      
      public void DoConfiguring(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            // do setup to define the key and table
      }
   }
}
```

File 2:

```
namespace ProjectB.Models {
   public class ClassA: BaseProject.Models.ClassA {
      public ClassC NavPropertyToAnotherClass { get; set; }
      public void DoConfiguring(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            // do setup for nav property here
      }
   }
}
```

In this scenario, all of BaseProject's models are configured, then all of ProjectB's models are configured. I want to have all the data in 1 table as defined in the configuring for ClassA. I'm not adding any additional columns or information. I just want to be able to use ClassB as if it is ClassA only with additional navigation properties set up.

I've run into discriminator issues and a couple other small things that are stopping. Is my setup for this wrong, or is this type of problem not currently solvable with inheritance and EF Core.

EDIT:
The end goal is to be able add navigational properties, as new relationships are made, to an inherited model so the base model and entities can almost remain a constant.

A different attempt to explain how I envision it working out.

```
//----------- File ---------------//
namespace BaseProject.Models {
    public class Person {
        public int Id { get;set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int? ParentOneId { get; set; }
        public int? ParentTwoId { get; set; }
        
        public Person ParentOne { get; set; }
        public Person ParentTwo { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Person> ChildrenOne { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Person> ChildrenTwo { get; set; }
        
        public void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            var builder = modelBuilder.Entity<Person>();
            builder.HasMany(l => l.ChildrenOne)
                .WithOne(co => co.ParentOne)
                .HasForeignKey(co => co.ParentOneId);
            
            builder.HasMany(l => l.ChildrenTwo)
                .WithOne(co => co.ParentTwo)
                .HasForeignKey(co => co.ParentTwoId);
                
            builder.ToTable("dbo", "Person");
            
            builder.HasKey(f => f.Id);
        }
    }
}
//--------------------------//

//----------- File ---------------//
namespace BaseProject.Contexts {
    public class BaseContext : DbContext {
        
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            new Person().OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
//--------------------------//

//----------- File ---------------//
namespace ExtraCurricularProject.Models {
    public class ExtraCurricular {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        // other stuff
        
        public ICollection<PersonExtraCurricular> PersonExtraCurriculars { get; set; }
        public void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            var builder = modelBuilder.Entity<ExtraCurricular>();
                
            builder.ToTable("dbo", "ExtraCurricular");
            
            builder.HasKey(f => f.Id);
        }
    }
}
//----------------------------//


//----------- File ---------------//
namespace ExtraCurricularProject.Models {
    public class Person : BaseProject.Models.Person {
    
        public ICollection<PersonExtraCurricular> PersonExtraCurriculars { get; set; }
        
        public void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {

        }
    }
}
//--------------------------//


//----------- File ---------------//
namespace ExtraCurricularProject.Models {
    public class PersonExtraCurricular {
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public int ExtraCurricularId { get; set; }
        
        public Person Person { get; set; }
        public ExtraCurricular ExtraCurricular { get; set; }
        
        public void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            var builder = modelBuilder.Entity<PersonExtraCurricular>();
            builder.HasOne(pec => pec.Person)
                .WithMany(p => p.PersonExtraCurriculars)
                .HasForeignKey<PersonExtraCurricular>(pec => pec.PersonId);
            
            builder.HasOne(pec => pec.ExtraCurricular)
                .WithMany(ec => ec.PersonExtraCurriculars)
                .HasForeignKey<PersonExtraCurricular>(pec => pec.ExtraCurricularId);
                
            builder.ToTable("dbo", "PersonExtraCurricular");
            
            builder.HasKey(pec => new { pec.PersonId, pec.ExtraCurricularId });
        }
    }
}
//--------------------------//

//----------- File ---------------//
namespace ExtraCurricularProject.Contexts {
    public class ExtraCurricularContext : BaseContext {
        
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            new Person().OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            new ExtraCurricular().OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            new PersonExtraCurricular().OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
//--------------------------//
```

Trying to use this type of pattern it says that I need a discriminator, but I don't want to have BaseProject.Models.Person and ExtraCurricularProject.Models.Person bring back different data, I just want ExtraCurricularProject.Models.Person to be able to access those other navigational properties.

Comment: Where do these `DoConfiguring` methods run? It's not clear if both classes are configured. (Assuming that the second `ClassA` is actually `ClassB`).

Comment: I added another attempt to see if it better captures how I envision it mapping out

Answer (score 0):

> To note: ... EF setup does not impact actual creation of SQL objects.

That's incorrect. Once you add properties to derived class, you need to bring EF in sync with the database - in other words, update the tables and relationship. And once you do that, EF tries to map your hierarchy to the tables (assuming you use EF Core 5), and that's why you get errors with `Discriminator` column (which is EF way to handle the hierarchy).

Now, this only happens if you have `ProjectB.ClassA` in the `DbContext`. Do you? If you don't then the root cause is different. Please show `DbContext` code. You hint that there is base and derived classes there as well - which is a little puzzling and is probably the *real* cause of the problem.

Also, please show the error that you are getting

Comment: I'm doing a bad job of describing my preferred outcome. Basically I want to have a project that has a DbContext with the base information about some tables and other projects to be able to inherit from that base information and add navigational properties to their specific tables. I don't want the base context and definition to have to know about ALL of the tables that have a dependent foreign key on it.

Comment: There is `DbContext` (to represent the database) and many `DbSet`s (to represent the tables). You don't need to subclass `DbContext`. You *can* derive from `DbSet` classes, and as long as you don't mark derived classes themselves as  `DbSet` - they won't be persisted in the database. But it looks like you *want* to persist information from derived classes - "navigational properties" are mapped to foreign keys. The statement "I don't want the base context to know about the tables..." doesn't make sense. Maybe start from the beginning and explain what you actually want to do!

Comment: I'm trying Felix D: